# how to check null json array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
function successCallback(responseObj)
{
      //alert(JSON.stringify(responseObj));
      $.each(responseObj.mname, function (i, mname) {
      var array=responseObj.mname[i].rname;
});
```

here **JSON.stringify(responseObj)** contains json response like

```
{"mname":
        [{
           "mName":"abc",
           "url":"abc.com",
           "pname":[{
                     "mName":"abc"
                   }],
           "rname":null
        }]
}
```

here i want to check the value of rname for null value.
i tried using

```
var array=responseObj.mname[i].rname;
 if( !$.isArray(array) ||  !array.length  ) {

   alert("currently no referral program available from this brand "); 
}
```

but its for empty value .how can i check for null value..?

Comment: `array === null` ??? Or just `if(array)`

Comment: The problem is that the json is not valid, make sure you are receiving a valid json, and then try to check it's values ( do it like @A.Wolff comment )

Comment: i m getting right json resposne..may be i wrote here wrong.but just i want to know how can i check null array means suppose {"rname":null} then how can i check it as a null

Answer (score 0):

use this,problem is you could not assign array value directly.use  `array.puse()` method.

```
    var array = new Array();
       array.push(responseObj.mname[0].rname);
       alert(array.length);
      if (array[0] ===null) {
          alert("array is NULL");
      }
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YtFpB/5/)

Comment: declare array as global

Comment: still not working.i m able to do this for empty array like{ "rname":[]) but not getting to do for the null array.